# How we convert currency in mail template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun, email-templates

I am using mailgun for sending mail of invoice copies but I want to display the amount in a formatted way. 
earlier it displays like USD 305050.00

While sending the amount to the template I converted into a string and I try to change it but it's not working

USD 305,050.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to convert any number string to USD formatted string :

```
function convert(str){
    const NUMBER_REGEX = /0*(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?/;
    const USD = /[0-9]{1,3}/g
    var match = str.match(NUMBER_REGEX);
    var result = "";
    if(match){
        let mantissa = match[1] ? match[1] : "";
        let exponent = match[2] ? match[2] : "";
        mantissa = mantissa.split("").reverse().join("").match(USD).map(function(value){
                return value.split("").reverse().join("");
            }).reverse().join(",");
        return mantissa + exponent;
    }
}
convert("1234567");
```